# want to display images next to people's names or photos on my website down to down like facebook

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to display all the image in my webpage that is uploaded by User down to down with User photo at side of this like Facebook. Kindly any one can suggest or have the website link from where  i can take some references.

Thnax
Santosh Sahu

Comment: What does "down to down" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm...it depends on how you store used ids.  A simple way could be to show a gravatar link.